# How difficult and real are David Attenborough's documentaries?

Tags: documentary

I have seen many David Attenborough's documentaries on animals and birds. The kind of shoots that they do in North Pole or under water or in deep forests on mountains - it seems like their team must spend a lot of time to do it.

How do they stay steady for such shoots. I mean they must eat or sleep. They shoot so close to animals even at night, and it still does not disturb them at all.

The commentaries given by David are so detailed. He describes the behavior of fishes as if he is absolutely sure what the fish is thinking. I mean is it that precise? I sometimes find it unreal but he has been doing this for so long.

Comment: BBC Natural History Unit (Based in Bristol,UK) are the teams behind the scenes http://www.bbc.co.uk/production/factual/programmesandshows/natural-history-unit general info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC_Natural_History_Unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most David Attenborough documentaries now feature a small 'How it's made' style film at the end of them, intended to address curious minds such as yours and demonstrate the complexity required of the shoots.

Obviously your question of how 'real' the documentaries are can be answered with *entirely real*.. but for a case-by-case breakdown of the individual shoots, it's best to watch the documentaries themselves.